# How can I get Posh-Git to launch using 'External Tools' in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, external-tools

The GitHb client installs Posh-Git as a ClickOnce application with a target of `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell`.  Visual Studio 2013 does not like this when I plug it into the 'External Tools' area.  I've tried pulling the arguments out, wrapping in quotes, etc.

The goal is to be in a project and quickly launch Posh-Git in the project directory I'm working in.

Comment: Plugging in the above into a batch file and referencing the batch file works, and will suffice.  However, it'd be nice to just handle it directly in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Add external tools and point to a batch file.  Add the arguments listed below in the image.  This assumes that your Git repository is one folder up from a 'Solution' directory.

[image: External Tools]

2.) The batch file should have the following contents (Replace 'Administrator' with the appropriate user):

```
@echo off
echo Starting with switches:  %*
echo.
echo.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms %*
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply launch the GitHub for Windows shell, use the following values:

Command: `%comspec%`

Arguments: `/c %localappdata%\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell`

However, this will not start the shell in the project directory. I can't find a way to make the GitHub for Windows shell do that. I think it always uses the default clone path. To specify the directory, we need to go directly to PowerShell:

Command: `powershell.exe`

Arguments: `-NoExit cd ""$(SolutionDir)""`

If you have either GitHub for Windows or posh-git installed, this should work.